# Directory for external files in the standard maven directory layout

Tags: java, maven, gradle, desktop-application, project-structure

In Java, we have two different approaches for loading data into the application.

If a file is packed into the jar (call it *resource* file) we get its `InputStream` by `Class.getResourceAsStream()` method.

If a file is not inside the jar (call it *external* file) we use `new FileInputStream()`.

If I understand correctly, the distinction between *resource* and *external* files is due to the fact that the former are required for the application to launch and run properly (therefore packed into an executable jar - shouldn't be modified) and the latter are rather optional and may or may be not provided by the user.

In [the standard maven directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) we put our *resource* files in the `src/main/resources` directory so they are included in the jar when building a project. **But I can't figure out what the proper directory for *external* files is.**

In the distributed version of my application I want to provide a certain set of default *external* files, so I need to put them somewhere in the project structure. What is the best location?

So far, I've seen `src/main/webapp` (which doesn't seem appropriate for desktop applications) and `src/main/conf` (which seems to get out of use and besides the *external* files may be of different types - not only text).

A custom directory like `src/main/assets` or `src/main/data`? Or maybe there should be another source directory next to the `main` and `test`?

I'll be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Is the distribution version packaged into zip kind like archive ?

Comment: Yes, I plan to pack executable jar and _external_ files to the one zip.

Comment: Everything that is not on the page you quoted is not part of the "standard". Any other location is either pure preference of the conventional folder that some plugin suggests. In that this question is primarily opinion based or like "recommend a tool / library / Maven plugin" which both make this question off-topic on Stackoverflow unfortunately.

Comment: So the best to create a separate module which might be called `dist` and put there the files you need into the directories you like. Than you can use a combination of maven-assembly-plugin and maybe appassembler-maven-plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is an external file, it can't be under src, you can put it under (for example) static_content (a folder next to the POM.xml) and add this to your POM

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            target/static_content/csvs
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                               <directory>static_content/csvs</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly not what maven is designed to do.

There is, however, a plugin designed to make deployment assemblies with executable jars and their wrappers called appassembler which we use to do this.  It consider what you call external files as configuration files, which are found in `src/main/config`.

See http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/